# AMD Sempron X4 3850 on Ubuntu 18.10 Server

Tags: drivers, radeon, 18.10

I have just upgraded my server OS from version 16.04 LTS to 18.10 and I noticed HDMI disconnects after BIOS screen. (I can connect with SSH) I added `nomodeset` to grub options and this fixed the issue. However, Ubuntu 18.10 does not seem to have `Radeon HD 8280 / R3 Series` driver. Could you please guide me?

**lspci:** `00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8280 / R3 Series]`

Comment: The upgrade path from 16.04 LTS is to 18.04 LTS (not 18.10) so can you please confirm your Ubuntu release?  The Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.10 is not tested & not an intended or supported path.

Comment: I mean I installed new 18.10 after formatting disk with 16.04 LTS. The point is why does Radeon driver did not installed itself.

Comment: I realize you're asking about video, but your description of how you got there is unsupported & untested and may be very significant to your problem (ie. maybe your cause).  Server does not use graphics so video drivers are not that important as you only need text to display. I'd suggest adding `sudo lshw -C video` to your question (ie. list hardware of class=network). I'm still confused by format in 16.04 LTS & install 18.10 - was it a clean install (ie. format) or unclean (no format)?  What was on it before you installed your 18.10  (if no-format & 16.04 was desktop - probable driver issues)